# putting a loop on a switch-case. exit menu when option 5 is selected by user

Tags: java, loops, menu, switch-statement

i have a switch case of 5 cases and each case has a different task to do. i want to make it so that when the user choses an option of the case and the task is done by the program, the menu comes up again and the user can keep choosing something from the menu until the user choses menu option 5 which quits.

so far I have:

```
//sys.out to print the menu options

            System.out.print("Enter the number of your choosing: ");
            menu = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println();


            switch (menu) {

            case 1:
            //code
            break;
            case 2:
            //code
            break;
            case 3:
            //code
            break;
            case 4:
            //code
            break;
            case 5:
            //code
            break;
            case 12:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
int menu = 0;
//you already said it: "the user can keep choosing something from 
//the menu until the user choses menu option 5"
while(menu != 5) {

    System.out.print("Enter the number of your choosing: ");
    menu = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    switch(menu){
        case 1: ...
        ...
        case 5: 
           break;
        default: System.out.println("Not supported.");
           break;
    }
}

//exit...
```

Comment: this just causes the option that i chose (eg if i chose case 2 which does a task) to keep running continuously non stop

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getItem ()
{
    int item = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter");
        item = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
    }
    while (item < 0 || item > 5);
    return item;
}

public void start ()
{
    int item;
    show ();
    item = getItem();
    switch (item)
        {
            case 1: code    break;
            .......
            case 5: code    break;
         }
    while (item !=0)
        System.out.println("buye");
```